# What does Linux Kernel 0.01 Support? (Processor Architecture)

Tags: linux, architecture, linux-kernel, kernel, low-level

I would like to learn about low-level development, but find the latest Linux kernels to be too much to read. I found that 0.01 is much easier to read, and thus, I would like to use it for my own educational purposes. Anyone know if VirtualBox can run it, and if not, what hardware/virtualization software could?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it only supports x86 (80386 to be precise). You can find more details about k0.01 [here](http://pramode2.tripod.com/kerneldocs/).

Comment: I would try dosbox or bochs

Answer (score 0):

Kernel only supports 80386 (x86).